# Performance boost long MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm coming from finance side not programming but with some personal readings.
I've 2 tables, one includes data about the clients such as their balance on daily basis, total number of rows is 1.7 million, and another table includes the commissions paid by each client and it's a bit smaller table, 
I want to see the data for the last day of the first big table with a sum of total profits for each client for the whole history registered in the table, plus the total commissions paid from the other table.
I used the following query:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(day, '%e %b %Y') AS 'Date',
m.account_number,
equity,
@total:=(SELECT 
        ROUND(SUM(profits), 2)
    FROM
        gbp
    WHERE
        account_number = m.account_number) AS Absolute_return,
commissions.Total AS Commissions FROM
gbp m
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    MAX(id) max_msg_id
FROM
    gbp
GROUP BY account_number) mc ON m.id = mc.max_msg_id
    INNER JOIN
commissions ON  commissions.account_number = m.account_number GROUP BY account_number
```

The code is working and generating the desired results, it's just takes too much time to get the results, I was thinking if there's a better way to make the query, I'm also using indexes for all tables based on account_number column.

Comment: daily basis, sorry English isn't my native , question edited

Comment: No worries, thanks for the clarification :). How much time is "`too much time`". Is this 10 seconds or 10 minutes, for instance?

Comment: Reading [this similar(ish) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486376/mysql-query-optimisation-for-browse-tracker)  whereby the OP wants to make their query run faster, the answers here indicate more that rather than editing the query itself you can either `partition` the table or use `summary tables`. I'll leave it to someone who knows more to recommend or dismiss either of these suggestions.

Comment: And add an index to your `gbp.id` column, too.